# when I add library dependencies in pom.xml, jetty servlet container fails to run properly

Tags: java, maven, jetty, web-development-server

I have a simple java web app with spring.
Then I added

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
        <artifactId>crypto</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
        <artifactId>abi</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

to the pom.xml

Now when I execute `mvn jetty:run` I get (which prints after a couple of minutes)

```
[WARNING] Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@4784efd9{/crowdfunding,file:/C:/Users/d/eclipse-jee-workspace/crowdfunding/src/main/webapp/,STARTING}{file:/C:/Users/d/eclipse-jee-workspace/crowdfunding/src/main/webapp/}
java.lang.Exception: Timeout scanning annotations
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations (AnnotationConfiguration.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure (AnnotationConfiguration.java:447)
```

and a 503 error on my browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default scan will wait 60 seconds (1 minute) to scan all of the `WEB-INF/classes` and `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar` files.

This can be configured to be longer.
But if it's taking that long already then you might have ...

- A very slow computer (you didn't say)
- A very large set of `WEB-INF/lib` entries (you didn't tell us this either)
- A fault in one of your `WEB-INF/lib` entries (a bad jar file, quite common actually)
- A configuration of your server classes that conflicts with your WebApp (seen more often on embedded-jetty usage then standalone `jetty-home` usage)
- A configuration of your `WebAppContext` with a custom classloader (this is NOT recommended, if you do have this, then you are on your own, as everything below here assumes a normal WebAppClassloader)
- A configuration of your `WebAppContext` that inverts the Servlet standard parent loader priority (if you have set this `setParentLoaderPriority()`, then comment out that call and try again)

Lets assume you either have bad jar files or conflicting dependencies.

What does those 3 dependencies pull in?

```sh
$ mvn dependency:tree
...(snip)...
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ huge-war ---
[INFO] org.eclipse.jetty.demo:huge-war:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.web3j:core:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.web3j:tuples:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-unixsocket:jar:0.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-ffi:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:native:1.2.16:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-a64asm:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.github.jnr:jnr-x86asm:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-constants:jar:0.9.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-enxio:jar:0.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.jnr:jnr-posix:jar:3.0.47:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.web3j:crypto:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.web3j:rlp:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.web3j:utils:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] \- org.web3j:abi:jar:4.2.0:compile
```

The unixsocket classes are going to be problematic from within a WebApp, as the classloader isolation and various protections that the Servlet container brings in means those native classes / libs will not work when executed from with a ServletContext's locked down environment.

But that wouldn't prevent the webapp from starting up, just would prevent IPC / UnixSocket behaviors at runtime.

I also see `org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:compile`, which is on the old side.

Jetty ships with asm 7.0

```sh
$ ls -la ~/code/jetty/distros/jetty-home-9.4.18.v20190429/lib/annotations/
total 316
drwxr-xr-x  2 joakim joakim   4096 May  1 13:09 ./
drwxr-xr-x 14 joakim joakim   4096 May  1 13:09 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 joakim joakim 113676 Nov  2  2018 asm-7.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 joakim joakim  33317 Nov  2  2018 asm-analysis-7.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 joakim joakim  79850 Nov  2  2018 asm-commons-7.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 joakim joakim  50399 Nov  2  2018 asm-tree-7.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 joakim joakim  26430 Jan 31 15:09 javax.annotation-api-1.3.jar
```

Depending on how you start Jetty, this could be a source of initialization and annotation / bytecode scanning issues.  As asm 5.0 and asm 7.0 are not fully binary compatible (at least from the point of view of what Jetty needs/uses)

All in all, there's nothing [untowards](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/untoward) about the resolved / effective list of dependencies that the 3 `<dependency>` entries you are asking about.

So lets see what happens if you attempt to deploy a webapp with just those 3 dependencies, complete with annotation scanning ...

```sh
$ cat start.ini
--module=http
jetty.http.port=8080
--module=deploy
--module=annotations

$ ls -la webapps/
total 10500
drwxr-xr-x 2 joakim joakim     4096 May 19 10:59 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 joakim joakim     4096 May 19 10:58 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 joakim joakim 10742370 May 19 10:58 demo-with-w3j-libs.war

$ java -jar ~/code/jetty/distros/jetty-home-9.4.18.v20190429/start.jar 
java -jar ~/code/jetty/distros/jetty-home-9.4.18.v20190429/start.jar
2019-05-19 11:11:02.993:INFO::main: Logging initialized @397ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2019-05-19 11:11:03.182:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.18.v20190429; built: 2019-04-29T20:42:08.989Z; git: e1bc35120a6617ee3df052294e433f3a25ce7097; jvm 11.0.3+7
2019-05-19 11:11:03.195:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///home/joakim/code/jetty/stackoverflow/huge-war/webapps/] at interval 1
2019-05-19 11:11:03.896:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=436ms
2019-05-19 11:11:03.902:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /demo-with-w3j-libs, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2019-05-19 11:11:03.911:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2019-05-19 11:11:03.911:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2019-05-19 11:11:03.912:INFO:oejs.session:main: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
2019-05-19 11:11:03.929:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@75437611{Demo of a WebApp with a large WEB-INF/lib,/demo-with-w3j-libs,file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-demo-with-w3j-libs.war-_demo-with-w3j-libs-any-5411225940231111244.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/demo-with-w3j-libs.war}
2019-05-19 11:11:04.236:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=184ms
2019-05-19 11:11:04.237:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /huge-war, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2019-05-19 11:11:04.240:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6f7923a5{Demo of a WebApp with a large WEB-INF/lib,/huge-war,file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-huge-war.war-_huge-war-any-2121417525584312936.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/huge-war.war}
2019-05-19 11:11:04.295:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@52c3cb31{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2019-05-19 11:11:04.295:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @1700ms
```

Yup, as I expected, it will init just fine.  In fact it took less then 184ms to scan that WAR (on my machine) ..

```
2019-05-19 11:11:04.236:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=184ms
```

Perhaps your initialization can show you what's happening.

Run with DEBUG turned on for both `org.eclipse.jetty.annotations` and `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp` and see if any exceptions are presented.  Also pay attention to the timings reported by the annotation scan, it could point at either a specific problematic jar or an overall timing issue with the entire set of libraries you have.

Example of starting jetty with StdErrLog specific properties to enable debug on the 2 packages `org.eclipse.jetty.annotations` and `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp`.

The output will show you issues with the JAR files and timings for each jar file scanned. Look for "Scanning elapsed time", the lines afterwords will tell you the timing for each JAR file in your webapp.

```
$ java -jar ~/code/jetty/distros/jetty-home-9.4.18.v20190429/start.jar -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.annotations.LEVEL=DEBUG -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.webapp.LEVEL=DEBUG
...(snip)...
2019-05-19 11:15:14.796:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp1571967156-41: Not a class: jni/Darwin/libjffi-1.2.jnilib
2019-05-19 11:15:14.796:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp1571967156-41: Not a class: jni/aarch64-Linux/libjffi-1.2.so
2019-05-19 11:15:14.796:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp1571967156-41: Not a class: jni/arm-Linux/libjffi-1.2.so
2019-05-19 11:15:14.797:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp1571967156-41: Not a class: jni/i386-Linux/libjffi-1.2.so
2019-05-19 11:15:14.797:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp1571967156-41: Not a class: jni/i386-SunOS/libjffi-1.2.so
2019-05-19 11:15:14.797:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp1571967156-41: Not a class: jni/i386-Windows/jffi-1.2.dll
2019-05-19 11:15:14.797:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp1571967156-41: Not a class: jni/ppc-AIX/libjffi-1.2.a
2019-05-19 11:15:14.797:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp1571967156-41: Not a class: jni/ppc64-Linux/libjffi-1.2.so
2019-05-19 11:15:14.800:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp1571967156-41: Not a class: jni/ppc64le-Linux/libjffi-1.2.so
2019-05-19 11:15:14.800:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp1571967156-41: Not a class: jni/sparcv9-Linux/libjffi-1.2.so
2019-05-19 11:15:14.800:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp1571967156-41: Not a class: jni/sparcv9-SunOS/libjffi-1.2.so
2019-05-19 11:15:14.800:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp1571967156-41: Not a class: jni/x86_64-FreeBSD/libjffi-1.2.so
2019-05-19 11:15:14.800:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp1571967156-41: Not a class: jni/x86_64-Linux/libjffi-1.2.so
2019-05-19 11:15:14.801:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp1571967156-41: Not a class: jni/x86_64-OpenBSD/libjffi-1.2.so
2019-05-19 11:15:14.801:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp1571967156-41: Not a class: jni/x86_64-SunOS/libjffi-1.2.so
2019-05-19 11:15:14.801:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp1571967156-41: Not a class: jni/x86_64-Windows/jffi-1.2.dll
...(snip)...
2019-05-19 11:15:15.393:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=654ms
2019-05-19 11:15:15.393:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanned file:///home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/jetty-home-9.4.18.v20190429/lib/servlet-api-3.1.jar in 141ms
2019-05-19 11:15:15.393:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanned file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-demo-with-w3j-libs.war-_demo-with-w3j-libs-any-14235900391383929769.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/ in 1ms
2019-05-19 11:15:15.393:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanned file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-demo-with-w3j-libs.war-_demo-with-w3j-libs-any-14235900391383929769.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/Java-WebSocket-1.3.8.jar in 144ms
2019-05-19 11:15:15.393:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanned file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-demo-with-w3j-libs.war-_demo-with-w3j-libs-any-14235900391383929769.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/abi-4.2.0.jar in 163ms
2019-05-19 11:15:15.393:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanned file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-demo-with-w3j-libs.war-_demo-with-w3j-libs-any-14235900391383929769.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/asm-5.0.3.jar in 126ms
...(snip)...
2019-05-19 11:15:15.394:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanned 1 container path jars, 31 WEB-INF/lib jars, 1 WEB-INF/classes dirs in 654ms for context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@75437611{demo-with-w3j-libs,/demo-with-w3j-libs,file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-demo-with-w3j-libs.war-_demo-with-w3j-libs-any-14235900391383929769.dir/webapp/,STARTING}{/demo-with-w3j-libs.war}
```

Finally, if you just have a slow computer, and just want to set that timeout to something larger, you can set the `org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.maxWait` value (in seconds) to something higher.

That can be set as a ServletContext attribute, or a Server attribute, or a System property (searched in that order).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply, I hope this will useful for more users in the future. It was indeed resolved by increasing the time out using the maxWait you mentioned at the end. I should have read and interpreted the error message more calmly, as it was kinda obvious in retrospect :)